# How does sortWith in Scala work in terms of iterating a tuple?

Tags: scala, scala-3

A list can be iterated as follows:

```
scala> val thrill = "Will" :: "fill" :: "until" :: Nil
val thrill: List[String] = List(Will, fill, until)
scala> thrill.map(s => s + "y")
val res14: List[String] = List(Willy, filly, untily)
```

The above code first creates a list and then the second command creates a map with an iterable called as 's', the map creates a new string from 's' by appending the char 'y'.

However, I do not understand the following iteration process:

```
scala> thrill.sortWith((s,t) => s.charAt(0).toLower < t.charAt(0).toLower)
val res19: List[String] = List(fill, until, Will)
```

Does the tuple `(s,t)` take two elements of `thrill` at once and compares them? How is sorting performed exactly using this syntax/function?

Comment: My I ask why this is tagged [tag:scala-3]?

Comment: In case it helps, [here](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#sortWith(lt:(A,A)=%3EBoolean):C) is the documentation for `sortWith`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes the function compares two elements at a time to determine their `ordering`.

[The implementation](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/collection/Seq.scala#L692) of `sortWith` falls back on Java's `Array.sort` [(docs)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(T%5B%5D,%20java.util.Comparator)) with the following signature

```
sort(T[] a, Comparator<? super T> c)
```

which takes in an `Array of T` and a comparator, equipped with a binary function that can compare any two elements of the set of possible values of `T` and give you some information about how they relate to each other (as in should come before, same or after based on your function).

Behind the scenes it is really just an iterative merge sort details of which can be found on the [wikipedia page for merge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort)

Leaving the optimizations aside, if you aren't familiar with it, merge sort, which is a divide and conquer algorithm, simply breaks down the collection you have until you have groups of 2 elements and then merges the smaller lists in a sorted way simply by comparing 2 elements at a time, which is where the binary comparison function you pass in comes to play.

i.e.

```
List(4, 11, 2, 1, 9, 0) //original list
```

Break down to chunks:

```
[4, 11], [2, 1], [9, 0]
```

Sort internally:

```
[4, 11], [1, 2], [0, 9]
```

Merge:

```
[1, 4, 11], [2], [0, 9]
[1, 2, 4, 11], [0, 9]
[0, 1, 2, 4, 11], [9]
[0, 1, 2, 4, 9, 11]
```

P.S. a nit picky detail, sortedWith takes in a `Function2` (a function of arity 2). This function you pass in is used to generate what we call an `Ordering` in Scala, which is then implicity converted to a `Comparator`. Above, I have linked to the implementation of `sorted` which is what `sortedWith` calls once it generates this `ordering` and which is where most of the sorting logic happens.

Comment: Actually, the function `sortWith` takes is a `Function2`. `Ordering` is a separate trait/typeclass. I think you accidentally linked the `sorted` method instead of `sortWith`. `sortWith` does call `sorted` by converting the inputted function into an `Ordering`, though.

Comment: @user that was a conscious decision to simplify the answer as I don't think all those conversions are relevant to what OP is confused about but I will edit the answer to make this decision clearer. I though that conversion would be clear by the sentence at the end `the function you pass in is used to generate what we call an Ordering` but apparently not. Thank you for your feedback

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean now. I was just confused by the link to `sorted`.

Answer (score 0):

Sorting is arranging the data in ascending or descending order. Sorted data helps us searching easily.
Scala uses **TimSort**, which is a hybrid of **Merge Sort and Insertion Sort**.

Here is signature of **sortWith** function in scala -

> def sortWith(lt: (A, A) => Boolean): Repr

The **sortWith** function Sorts this sequence according to a comparison function. it takes a comparator function and sort according to it.you can provide your own custom comparison function.

It will perform [Tim Sort](https://www.infopulse.com/blog/timsort-sorting-algorithm/) on the input list to result sorted output.